Hybris - Azure Cloud Hot-Folder and Cronjob input directory
we are moving our application from on-premise to ccv2, we have cronjob configured to load files and convert them into impex, there is input, archive and error directory defined in cronjob.
But in ccv2, we are using azure cloud hotfolder, is there a way to fetch input, error and archive directory from azure container and link to cronjob ?

there are some extensions in Hybris u can integrate them in ur project :
extensions
using them you can create a listener in your project to handle files from the blob container, just override some extensions properties :
connectionString
The next step is to add a configuration so that a container will be created automatically if it does not exist right after login.
containerName
i can resume all the process in this schema
resume
u can find more details in this link :
https://community.sap.com/t5/crm-and-cx-blogs-by-members/cloud-hot-folder-implementation/ba-p/13501668
